# Отцентрировать элемент используя содержащийся в нем элемент

Tags: html, css

Структура html следущая:

```
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы #c2 так располагался внутри #c1, чтобы #d2 был выровнен вертикально по центру #c1. Расттояние между #d1 и #d2 фиксировано.

Можно, чтобы работало только в последнем Chrome.

Уточняющая картинка:
[image]

Comment: высота d1 и d2 плавающие?

единственное что мне приходит на ум - выравнивать скриптом

Comment: @IVsevolod Да, плавающие. Скриптом я могу, но не хочется =)

Comment: c2 как-то неудобно и непонятно стоит — это обязательно? Нельзя ли его вообще убрать или растянуть на 100% во все стороны?

И еще, не логичнее было бы d1 поместить в d2? Как я понял, d2 привязан к d1?

Comment: @Bars, c2 вообще не важен, он невидимый.

Comment: @Bars, по поводу второго вопроса: зачем убирать d1 в d2? У меня в d2 текст.

Comment: Чтобы можно было позиционировать блок `d1` относительно блока `d2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я позволил себе немного изменить разметку: я поместил `#d1` вовнутрь `#d2`. [Вот такой вариант получился](http://jsfiddle.net/hphbU/):

```
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
    <div id="d1">
      <div id="d2">#d2</div>
      <div id="d1-content">#d1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если [еще немного поправить разметку](http://jsfiddle.net/hphbU/2/), то можно обойти и сложности с шириной блока `#c1` (я установил относительную ширину для `#c1`).

Comment: Круто! Только я не понял почему работает "bottom: 100%" если у родительского элемента явно не задан height? Я кстати тоже придумал решение, с использованием transform, сейчас приведу.

Comment: Абсолютно позиционированному элементу не обязательно знать высоту родителя. Фича :)

Comment: @Bars, значит мануалы, которые я читал, уже устарели.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/hRsJY/) которое я сочинил. Работает только в Chrome, но думаю его несложно адаптировать под любой современный браузер.

Comment: Занятно :) `translate` вычисляет % относительно своих собственных размеров? /* нужно читать спецификацию... */

Comment: @Bars, да.